# Get Vimeo video secured by password - C#

Tags: c#, .net, api, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm trying to make request on Vimeo endpoint to get video information, I have a video Id and the password but, I cannot find how to retrieve video information If it is password secured.
Below that's what I'm trying to do:

[image]

(I used - VimeoDotNet nuget package)

Offcourse I get error because didn't pass password to vimeo endpoint. How to handle with this? How to get Vimeo Video details which is secured by password, which ofcourse I have, but there is no place when I can use it in API, all advices appreciated.

VimeoApi Exception:

VimeoDotNet.Exceptions.VimeoApiException: 'Error retrieving account video.
Code: BadRequest
Message: {"invalid_parameters":[{"field":"password","error_code":2223,"error":"Whoops! Please enter a password.","developer_message":"Password not provided for a password protected video."}],"error":"You have provided an invalid parameter. Please contact developer of this application.","link":null,"developer_message":"The parameters passed to this API endpoint didn't pass Vimeo's validation. Please check the invalid_parameters list for more information.","error_code":2204}'

Comment: Please don't upload code in images, and read [ask]